# Guice: "Could not find suitable constructor" when suitable constructor supplied in FactoryBuilder

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice, factory

I'm using Guice for dependency injection, but I'm getting this error:

```
1) Could not find a suitable constructor in java.lang.Void. Classes must have either one (and only one) constructor annotated with @Inject or a zero-argument constructor that is not private.
  at java.lang.Void.class(Void.java:44)
  while locating java.lang.Void
  at com.myfeed.algorithm.clusterer.tree.wrapper.ItemSourceTreeWrapperFactory.create(ItemSourceTreeWrapperFactory.java:1)
```

What's especially odd is that it mentions java.lang.Void.

This is the **module code**: (I bind a class to itself, not an interface to a class)

```
install(new FactoryModuleBuilder().implement(
     new TypeLiteral<ItemSourceTreeWrapper<Document>>(){}, ItemSourceTreeWrapper.class
).build(new TypeLiteral<ItemSourceTreeWrapperFactory<Document>>(){}));
```

Here is **ItemSourceTreeWrapper constructor**:

```
@Inject
public ItemSourceTreeWrapper(@Assisted Tree<Item<Source>> treeToWrap, @Assisted ItemGroup itemGroup, Itemizer<Source> itemizer, SourceItemConverterFactory sourceItemConverterFactory) {
    this.treeToWrap = treeToWrap;
    this.itemizer = itemizer;
    sourceItemConverter = sourceItemConverterFactory.create(itemGroup, itemizer);
}
```

And here is the **factory interface**:

```
public interface ItemSourceTreeWrapperFactory<Source> {
    public void create(Tree<Item<Source>> treeToWrap, ItemGroup<Source> itemGroup);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your call to `implement()` looks suspicious - since `ItemSourceTreeWrapper` is generic, the second parameter should likely be using a `TypeLiteral<>`.  Furthermore, since you're implementing a class with itself, you should be able to omit the `implement()` call entirely.

But your actual problem is that in `ItemSourceTreeWrapperFactory`, `public void create(...)` should probably be `public ItemSourceTreeWrapper<Source> create(...)`.